# Finding "integrating factor" for this non-exact differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following differential equation

$$4y^{3}+7x\sin(x)+4x^{4}-(16\cos(y)-7x-\frac{7}{4}y^{2})y'=-e^{y-x}+\sinh(y)$$

We write the standard equation

$$(4y^{3}+7x\sin(x)+4x^{4}+e^{y-x}-\sinh(y))dx+(-16\cos(y)+7x+\frac{7}{4}y^{2})dy=0$$

So we have

$\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}=12y^{2}+e^{y-x}-\cosh(y)$

$\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}=7$

We can see $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}$ is not equal to $\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ that the differential equation is not exact and we need an integrating factor, which is the integrating factor in terms of $z(x,y)$. we have

$p(z)=\dfrac{12y^{2}+e^{y-x}-\cosh(y)-7}{{\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}}(-16\cos(y)+7x+\frac{7}{4}y^{2})-{\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}}(4y^{3}+7x\sin(x)+4x^{4}+e^{y-x}-\sinh(y))}$

The question here is to find the function $z(x,y)$ so that $p(z)$ is obtained in terms of $z(x,y)$ and the integral factor is obtained!

Comment: Yes .. im sure .. we should fine integral factor first! But how?!

Comment: It is exactly the same differential equation with the same form. That's exactly it! I wrote it correctly and I know it should be answered